# Document.write() doesn’t work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: js code]

[image: result]

Question: why doesn't it display all the styles I made?

Comment: What styles are you talking about?

Comment: You can use inline style. However it is bad practice to use `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` erases everything on the page including your styles. You'll have to include your styles with `document.write` . So you'll probably have to something like

```
function disptayQuestion(questionIndex) {   
    var q = questions [questionlndex] ;     
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourstyle.css">');
    document.write( (questionlndex + 1) + "." + q.question + "<br>" );
    document.write(q.optionA +  "<br>");
    document.write(q.optionB +  "<br>");
    document.write(q.optionC +  "<br>");
    document.write(q.optionD);  

}
```